# SharePoint JSOM Parsing values in a hyperlink field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-jsom

I have a value that looks like "mailto:a@b.com, mailto:a@b.com'.  This is basically a hyperlink field and I want to parse this properly using SharePoint JSOM.  I tried SP.FieldUrlValue, but it does not seem to have a method that lets you parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.get_url()` function on the actual item value to get the hyperlink URL, or the `.get_description()` function to get the hyperlink's display text.

```
var linkField = "internalColumnName";
var listName = "List Title";
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);   
clientContext.load(items);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,function(){ 
    var itemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
    while(itemEnumerator.moveNext()){   
        var item = itemEnumerator.get_current(); 
        var url = item.get_item(linkField).get_url(); // <-- Get URL
        var text = item.get_item(linkField).get_description(); // <-- Get Text
        alert(url + ", " + text);
    }     
}),Function.createDelegate(this,function(sender, args){alert(args.get_message());}));
```